# What should be mocked for an integration test?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, integration-testing

Upon reading Growing Object Orientated Software Guided by Tests, I learnt of test isolation and test fragility. The idea that each test should be very specific to a piece of code or functionality, and the overlap of code coverage by tests should be kept to a minimum.
The implied ideal that each change in the code should result in breaking only one test.
Avoiding spending time going through multiple broken tests to confirm that one change is the cause and if it is fixed by the test modifications.

Now this seems easy enough for unit tests, they are very isolated by their nature.
However when presented by integration tests, it seems hard to avoid having multiple tests exercising the same code paths, particularly when run in addition to the unit tests.

So my question, is what dependencies should be mocked when doing integration testing? Should anything be mocked at all? Should a single execution path be tested, and all side effects not directly relevant to this code path be mocked?

I'm toying with the idea of doing pairwise integration testing. Test one relationship between two objects, and mock everything else. Then changes in either one of these objects should have minimal impact on other integration tests, in addition to forming a complete chain of end-to-end tests by means of pairs.

Thanks for any info..

**Edit**: Just to clarify, I'm basically asking "How do I avoid large numbers of failing integrations tests during the normal course of development?". Which I assume is achieved by using mocks, and why I asked about what to mock.

**Update**: I've found a very interesting talk about Integration tests by J.B.Rainsberger, which I think answers this fairly well, if perhaps a bit controversially. The title is "Integration Tests are a Scam", so as you can guess, he does not advocate Integration Tests at all (end to end type tests).  The argument being that Integration Tests will always be far below the amount needed to thoroughly test the possible interactions (due to combinatoric explosion), and may give a false confidence.
Instead he recommends what he calls Collaboration Tests and Contract Tests. It's a 90 min talk and unfortunately the whiteboard is not very clear and there aren't code examples, so i'm still getting my head around it. When I have a clear explanation I'll write it here! Unless someone else beats me to it..

Here's a brief summary of Contract Tests. Sounds like Design by Contract type assertions, which I believe could/would be implemented in a Non-Virtual Interface pattern in C++.

http://thecodewhisperer.tumblr.com/post/1325859246/in-brief-contract-tests

Integration Tests are a Scam video talk:
http://www.infoq.com/presentations/integration-tests-scam

> Summary:
>
> Integration tests are a scam. You’re probably writing 2-5% of
>   the integration tests you need to test thoroughly. You’re probably
>   duplicating unit tests all over the place. Your integration tests
>   probably duplicate each other all over the place. When an integration
>   test fails, who knows what’s broken? Learn the two-pronged attack that
>   solves the problem: collaboration tests and contract tests.

Comment: While I have yet to read GOOS (shame on me), I am pretty certain that it is not talking about integration tests when it says that only one test should fail per one change.

Comment: I see, so you think the test fragility applies more to unit tests than integration tests? I gues integration tests would be considered inherently more fragile and expected to fail more often?

Comment: No, quite the contrary. Integration tests test a bigger picture, so as long as the functionality they test didn't change, they are not supposed to fail.

Comment: The problem though is when there's a valid change in behaviour. If the integration tests all use some particular object that changes, then all those tests will fail and require attention. And this could be a large number of tests, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: If you are changing functionality, you have to change some tests. There is no way around this. In reality however, I bet that the number of tests you need to change in response to a valid change in behavior is smaller than you might think.

Answer (score 3):

For integration tests you should mock the minimum amount of dependencies to get the test working, but not less :-)

Since the integration of the components in your system is obviously the thing you want to test during integration testing, you should use real implementations as much as possible. However, there are some compontents you obviously want to mock, since you don't want your integration tests to start mailing your users for instance. When you don't mock these dependencies, you obviously mock too little.

That doesn't mean btw that you shouldn't allow an integration test to send mails, but at least you want to replace the mail component with one that will only send mail to some internal test mail box.

Comment: The trouble I have is that in theory, I could mock everything, and the test could work. Such as a test for several objects to collaborate to calculate a value, I could just have a mock return that value.
Maybe some sort of TDD style approach could be used, to mock everything at first, to get it working, then gradually expand the integration test asserts until the mocks are insufficient and requires real code, with the total code coverage being the ultimate goal? I donno...gives me a headache thinking about it sometimes

Comment: <the total code coverage being the ultimate goal> Nope, shipped, working software is the ultimate goal. :) A reasonably high level of code coverage can help you with “working”. Aiming for 100% does not help with shipped and can harm “working”.

Comment: If there is such a goal as total coverage, it is not total *code* coverage but total *feature* coverage, i.e. every feature is covered by your tests.

Answer (score 2):

For integration tests I lean towards mocking the service rather than the representation for example using [mirage](http://rubygems.org/gems/mirage) instead of a 3rd party REST API and [Dumpster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/) rather than a real SMTP server.

This means that all layers of your code are tested, but none of the 3rd parties are tested so you are free to refactor without worrying that the tests will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Unit tests should have mock objects, but integration tests should have few if any mocks (otherwise what is being integrated ?)  I think it's overkill to do pairwise mocking; it will lead to an explosion of tests that might each take a long time and lots of copy and paste code which will be a pain to change if requirements change or new features are added later.

I think it's fine to to not have any mocks in the integration tests.  You should have everything mocked in the unit tests to know that each individual unit works as expected in isolation.  The integration test tests that everything works wired together.

Comment: The main problem I'm trying to solve, is when there is a valid change, how do you avoid having large numbers of failing integration tests? Without mocks, everything that touches the change will fail and require attention.

Comment: Depending on what's changed I think it's a good thing that integration tests would fail.  If an interface to one of the dependencies changes, the integration test SHOULD fail since we are testing that we are correctly communicating with our dependencies.

Comment: But my question to you would be, how many should fail? What's an acceptable number? In theory, if there's hundreds of tests, and they all rely on some essential component, like a database, then if that database changes, possibly hundreds of tests could fail.

Comment: Depends on how the database changes and how well you have separated your database layer. 
Lets take for example you have inherited a shoddy database design, but your object model is sane. You refactor some of the DB design. IMO no integration tests should fail.

Answer (score 0):

The discussion of **Contract/Collaborator** test pattern (described by JB Rainsberger in "Integration Tests are a Scam" mentioned in the question above). Relating to the question here - I interpreted his talk to mean that when you own the code for both the service side and the client side, then you should not need any integration test at all. Instead you should be able to rely on mocks which implement a contract.

The talk is a good reference for high level description of the pattern but doesn't go into detail (for me at least) about how to define or reference a contract from a collaborator.

One common example of the need for **Contract/Collaborator** pattern is between an API's server / client (for which you own the code of both). Here's how I've implemented it:

**Define the contract:**

First define the API Schema, if your API uses JSON you might consider [JSONSchema](http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/index.html). The schema definition can be considered the "Contract" of the API. (And as a side note, if you're about to do that, make sure you know about [RAML](http://raml.org/developers/raml-100-tutorial) or Swagger since they essentially make writing JSONSchema APIs alot easier)

**Create fixtures which implement the contract:**

- On the server side, mock out the client requests to allow unit testing of the requests/responses. To do this you will create client request fixtures (aka mocks). Once you have your API defined, validate the fixtures against the JSONSchema to ensure that they comply.  There are a host of schema validators - I currently use AJV (Javascript) and jsonschema (Python), but most languages should have an implementation.
- On the client(s) side you will likely mock out the server responses to allow unit testing of the requests. Follow the same pattern as the server, validating the request and response fixtures via JSONSchema.

If both the Client and the Server are validating their fixtures against the contract, then whenever the API Contract changes, the out of date implementations on both sides will fail JSONSchema validation and you'll know it's time to update your fixtures and possibly the code which relies on those fixtures.